# Comparing money amount in php

Tags: php

After having checked everywhere in vain I decided to post this problem here. I am Working on an online shop where the client needs to show automatically a "free shipping label" for all items that cost 100€ or more. I did make a function that worked with plain numbers (80€), but when the price is in this format (2.453,90€) it doesn´t.

I would really appreciate your help if you could shed some light on this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest storing "raw" versions of the values before formatng them to have the thousand separator.. This way you can compare the actual value and not the value that you are using for visual representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove dot  and put dot instead of comma for php to recognize this as a number:

```
$plainNumber = floor(str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","","2.453,90")));
if($plainNumber >= 100)
{
    //do intended stuff
}
```

Comment: This function has worked perfectly well for what I needed. You have saved me more hours of searching online. Thanks a lot Volkan.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions to transforms formatted numbers in raw numbers.

```
$number = preg_replace('/\./', '', $number);
$number = preg_replace('/,/', '.', $number);
```

You could also store raw numbers instead of formatted numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Stringified data types are a not uncommon beginner error. You should always handle numbers as [native numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php) and only convert to string when printing them.

When you use numbers, good old [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) become useful.